# catching the WM_DEVICECHANGE

Tags: c, windows, winapi, gcc, mingw

How to become aware of `WM_DEVICECHANGE` arrival?

`WndProc`'s overwritten. I catch the whole bunch of messages but none of them are of type `WM_DEVICECHANGE`. `RegisterDeviceNotification` makes the linker to complain that it can't find the function! So I'm stuck in this voodoo magic. Kindly help.

P.S.: of course I have been googling and stackoverflowing (lol) all this stuff for about 8 hours.

```
int CALLBACK WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
        LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
        LPTSTR lolclassname = "lolclass";
    WNDCLASS lolclass;
    HWND lolwindow;
    MSG lolmsg;
    UINT msgstatus;

    lolclass.style = CS_VREDRAW;
    lolclass.lpfnWndProc = &lol_wnd_proc;
    lolclass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    lolclass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    lolclass.hInstance = hInstance;
    lolclass.hIcon = NULL;
    lolclass.hCursor = NULL;
    lolclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_BACKGROUND + 1);
    lolclass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    lolclass.lpszClassName = lolclassname;
    if(!RegisterClass(&lolclass)) fail("RegisterClassEx");

    lolwindow = CreateWindow("lolclass", NULL, WS_MINIMIZE, CW_USEDEFAULT,
            CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
            HWND_MESSAGE, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    if(lolwindow == NULL) fail("CreateWindowEx");

    /*ShowWindow(lolwindow, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(lolwindow);*/

    do {
/*      if(!SetWindowPos(lolwindow, HWND_TOPMOST, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                    SWP_HIDEWINDOW))
            fail("SetWindowPos");*/
        msgstatus = GetMessage(&lolmsg, lolwindow, 0, 0);
        if(!msgstatus) break;
        if(msgstatus == - 1) fail("GetMessage");
        TranslateMessage(&lolmsg);
        DispatchMessage(&lolmsg);
        Sleep(1000);
    } while(1);

    return lolmsg.wParam;
}
```

`lol_wnd_pro`c is executed but never when it supposed to (on device change of course, am I clear?)

Comment: I think the description is not clear. Pls restructure and show some code, if possible

Comment: Why did you try to write the boilerplate code yourself instead of using one of the widely-distributed samples?

Comment: That *is* the problem with prefixing everything with 'lol'.  Even the operating system won't take you seriously.  Lol.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating a [message-only window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632599.aspx#message_only) which does not receive broadcasts:

> A message-only window enables you to send and receive messages. It is not visible, has no z-order, cannot be enumerated, and **does not receive broadcast messages**. The window simply dispatches messages.

So, you cannot use a message-only window and instead need to make a top-level window that is never shown. That's trivial to achieve — stop passing `HWND_MESSAGE` to `CreateWindow` and make sure that you never call `ShowWindow`.

---

As an aside, `Sleep(1000)` in the middle of a message loop is going to be a disaster. You need to pump messages in a timely fashion, not fall asleep on the job. You must get rid of that `Sleep`. Note that `GetMessage` will block if the queue is empty, so you don't need to worry about your application running hot.

Your message loop should look like this:

```
while( (bRet = GetMessage( &msg, NULL, 0, 0 )) != 0)
{ 
    if (bRet == -1)
    {
        // handle the error and possibly exit
    }
    else
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg); 
        DispatchMessage(&msg); 
    }
}
```